# State variable changes unpredictably - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a newbie in React. I need some help to solve this issue

**Code:**

```js
 this.state={
    testState: {
        testArray: [
            { name: "bob" },
            { name: "alice" },
            { name: "john" }
        ]
    }
}

testFn = () => {

        let a;
        a = { ...this.state.testState }; //using spread operator to copy the object instead of referencing
        a.testArray.map((obj) => {
            obj.name = "React is awesome"
        })
        console.log(this.state.testState)
    }
```

**Output:**

```
testArray: Array(3)
0: {name: "React is awesome"}
1: {name: "React is awesome"}
2: {name: "React is awesome"}
```

I have to modify `a` without altering the state. But here, the state is also changed along with the iteration.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: unrelated to the issue, but you're also using `.map()` for simple iteration and not using its return value. For simple iteration, you can use `.forEach` which is built for that sort of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The spread operator only does a shallow copy

To guarantee a full object copy use

`const copiedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourState))`

## Better solution

Sove it at the source. Don't make deep state, its actually a key part of writing objects in the state. You should keep them very shallow. In this case you are already way deep with Obj -> Array -> Obj.